# Weifenluo DockPanel - hide tab control

Tags: c#, tabs, dockpanel

Is there a way to hide the whole "tabs" strip that runs across the top of a DockPanel? I found a [very old page from '05](https://sourceforge.net/p/dockpanelsuite/discussion/402316/thread/ed3ef9a8/)  that said to set the `DockPanel.SdiDocument` to true, but the `SdiDocument` property doesn't seem to be around any more.

When this project was originally written (I'm not the original dev) this area was going to have multiple tabs but it has since been decided that there will only ever be one tab and that it can not be closed, so we don't need the "tabs" part of this control.

Honestly, it would probably be better if this was just a panel but it would be a *lot* of work to make that change so if anyone knows how to do this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/issues/296) for reference.

Problem seems to be the expected audience of this feature, but PRs are welcome.